# Approved PayPal SDK Payments don't appear on Sandbox Dashboard

Tags: ios, sandbox, paypal-sandbox, paypal

The didCompletePayment delegate method confirms the state of my payment is approved:

```
CurrencyCode: USD
Amount: 1.95
Short Description: avocado
Intent: sale
Processable: Already processed
Display: $1.95
Confirmation: {
    client =     {
        environment = mock;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.8.3";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    response =     {
        "create_time" = "2015-02-10T16:17:43Z";
        id = "PAY-NONETWORKPAYIDEXAMPLE123";
        intent = sale;
        state = approved;
    };
    "response_type" = payment;
}
Details: (null)
Shipping Address: (null)
Invoice Number: (null)
Custom: (null)
Soft Descriptor: (null)
BN code: (null)
```

However, when I go my Dashboard on Developer.PayPal.com, nothing shows up on my transactions page.

Any thoughts on what I could be missing or doing wrong? Is the payment completely verified at this point or do I have to do more logic on the server to verify it? I am already getting the bearer access token before I create the payment and get its info in the delegate callback, but am not sure what I am supposed to do with this token.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I realized what I was doing wrong.

I was previously using:

```
        PayPalMobile.preconnectWithEnvironment(PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork)
```

But needed to be using:

```
        PayPalMobile.preconnectWithEnvironment(PayPalEnvironmentSandbox)
```

Hope this helps someone else using PayPal SDK for iOS.